# Visual Studio - Auto-Generated Text

Tags: visual-studio

When I am using Visual Studio, I have grey text automatically generated to reflect various aspects of my code. I know that this is an option that can be turned off, but I don't know how. Anyone know how to turn off that feature?

I have a picture included here with the auto-generated text circled in yellow:

[image: Problem as stated above]